# I can't get the DISTANCE_DELTA and STEP_COUNT_DELTA at the same time

Tags: android, google-fit

Working with the Google Fit API at the moment and having a bit of trouble with the Sensors API. I try to get DISTANCE_DELTA and STEP_COUNT_DELTA  together. But when I run, I get onle steps or only distance. Not both

```
Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(client, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA,
                        DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA,
                    DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW, DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {

                    datasources.clear();
                    listeners.clear();
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        final DataType dataType = dataSource.getDataType();
                        if (    dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE) ||
                                dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)||
                                dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)) {

                            final OnDataPointListener listener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                    String msg = "onDataPoint: ";
                                    for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                        Value value = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                        msg += field + "=" + value + ", ";
                                        Log.d(TAG, msg);
                                    }

                                }
                            };
                            Fitness.SensorsApi.add(client,
                                    new SensorRequest.Builder()
                                            .setDataSource(dataSource)
                                            .setDataType(dataType)
                                            .setSamplingRate(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                            .build(),
                                    listener)
                                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                                listeners.add(listener);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Listener for " + dataType.getName() + " registered");

                                            } else {
                                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register listener for " + dataType.getName());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    datasourcesListener.onDatasourcesListed();
                }
            });
```